# streaming replication consideration

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12

I am asking for guidance.

I want to set up a replication between 3 servers : 1 master A, 2 slaves B and C. The master streams to 2 slaves. A to B is **logical replication**, whereas A to C is **streaming replication**

After I read some articles and I am now aware that streaming replication involves `pg_basebackup`, with the Slave pulling data from the Master.

Question :

1. I read the articles [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-physical-streaming-replication-with-postgresql-12-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [here](https://www.tecmint.com/configure-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-centos-8/). Which one is correct, `"ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses TO '*';"` OR `listen_addresses = 'your_primary_IP_address'`. I am just confused.
2. What are some considerations before I proceed the replication that involves 3 servers ?

Thank you
postgresql 12, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks how to enable network connections to your PostgreSQL cluster. You can use either method you describe, they are roughly equivalent for *most* cases. Changing `listen_addresses` requires a server restart, so plan accordingly.

The one consideration is if your host is multi-homed, that is, connected to multiple networks. If it is, and you don’t want to expose PostgreSQL to all of the networks, then specify the interface IPs of the networks you want to bind PostgreSQL to, and leave out the ones you don’t.

The special address ‘*’ tells PostgreSQL to bind to all available addresses. In most cases, that is just the server’s single IP. (And `localhost` but that is less important.)

If you have a firewall enabled then you will also need to allow connections through the firewall.

There are serious security implications to enabling network connections.  **NEVER** expose PostgreSQL to the unfiltered public Internet. Your database **will** be hacked and turned into a cryptocurrency miner if that happens. Use a firewall to limit access to just the replication clients.

The DigitalOcean article doesn’t mention it, so it might be in there by default on Ubuntu, but you  need an entry in `pg_hba.conf` telling PostgreSQL how to authenticate network clients. If you get authentication errors in the PostgreSQL log when the replication clients try to connect then that is likely the issue.

Comment: ok. thankyou @dwhitemv . how about the considerations I should think of related to the replication involving 3 servers ? I just edited the question. thanks again

Comment: Can you be more specific? Not sure what “consideration” you are worried about.

Comment: ok. What I am worried is that I can not achieve a smooth streaming replication. What do I have to pay attention to? maybe minimum memory, bandwidth, minimum processor, settings etc. The database is not large, currently around 500 GB max (and growing soon) and will be accessed concurrently by 700 users max

Comment: Hard to say without digging deep into your workload. 700 concurrent connections is a LOT for a database. But think of it this way — the write load on the clients will be the same as the server as the queries are the same. Please ask a new question if you want to discuss it further.